# First / FirstOrDefault not working as I would expect

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I am using nhibernate and I wrote a linq query and it is not returning what I expect.

```
public ParentA()
{
    public virtual Id {get; set;}
    public virtual Name {get; set;}
    public virtual IList<ChildA> ChidrenA {get; set;}

   public ParentA()
   {
       ChidrenA = new List<ChildA>();      
   }
}

public ChildA()
{
    public virtual Id {get; set;}
    public virtual Name {get; set;}
    public virtual IList<ChildB> ChidrenB {get; set;}
    public virtual ParentA ParenteA {get; set;}
   public ChildA()
   {
       ChidrenB = new List<ChildB>();      
   }
}

public ChildB()
{
    public virtual Id {get; set;}
    public virtual Name {get; set;}
    public virtual ChildA {get; set;}
}
```

The above code is my domains. The fluent nhibernate would be very basic and nothing special going on so I have not included it.

The query I have is

```
base.unitOfWork.Session.Query<ParentA>()
  .Where(x => x.Id == parentAId)
  .FetchMany(x => x.ChildrenA)
  .ThenFetchMany(x => x.ChildrenB)
  .FirstOrDefault();
```

**What I expected to happen**

It will find 1 or 0 parent records. If it does find that one record it will eager load all ChildrenA and then all ChildrenB.

**What is happening**

It finds 1 or 0 parent records. It then only takes 1 or 0 record for ChildrenA and ChildrenB.

Why is only taking the first found record for ChildrenA and ChildrenB?

If I change `FirstToDefault()` to `.toList()` I get everything I expect but I find it pointless as there should only be one record with that parent record.

Comment: Have you tried putting FirstOrDefault after the Where, but before the FetchMany statements?

Comment: @AaronHawkins - ya can't do that. If I do that then I can't use Fetches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving `.FirstOrDefault` to directly after the `.Where` clause:

```
.Where(x => x.Id == parentAId).FirstOrDefault()...
```

Comment: Then you could also replace `.Where()` with `FirstOrDefault()` as it basically does the same thing.

FirstOrDefault( x => x.Id == parentAId )...

Comment: @LazyTarget: Very good point :)

Comment: Ya that's what I thought and tried to move FirstOrDefault() to after the where but then I lost the fetches. It would not let me use them.

Answer (score 3):

Actually you dont need the Where ...First or default takes lambda expression

```
  .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == parentAId).
```

So instead of Where , use the the above statement